# How to tell what operating system users are using?

Tags: java

I was wondering is there any code I could use to tell what operating system viewers of my website are using. I realized that a lot of download websites do this to prompt you to Mac downloads or PC downloads. Does anyone know anything to help? Thank you very much!

Comment: I understand this is Java, but what platform?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, check the client [User Agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent). How you do that depends on the server side framework you're using.

Answer (score 1):

There is usually a property in the HTTP header sent to the web server.

http://myhttp.info/

On my machine the `User Agent` is the `Linux x86_64` version.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to tell from the user-agent string, which is described on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent_string#User_agent_identification). Of course, browsers and people may have their user-agent strings lie.  You would access this with:

```
// From some source.  This could be a method parameter instead.
final HTTPServletRequest request;

final String userAgent = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
```

Now, use string manipulation to guess whether the user is using OSX, Windows, Linux, UNIX, or a more exotic system. But give the user an opportunity to choose any download.